# A String.prototype.diff() line by line

Tags: javascript

I'm comparing large groups of text strings that need to have their differences highlighted. We would like it so that when there is a difference found on a line of text (\n), that line is kept and crossed out. Then the new line is highlighted and placed under it.

so an example would be

oldtext:
He ran 12 yards.
He got in his car.
and drove away.

newtext:
He ran 50 yards.
He got in his car.
and turned it on.

output:
<strike>He ran 12 yards.</strike>
**He ran 50 yards.**
He got in his car.
<strike>and drove away.</strike>
**and turned it on.**

I managed to make something work letter by letter but it wasn't satisfactory.

```
String.prototype.largestMatch = function largestMatch( otherString ){

    if( otherString.length < this.length )
      return otherString.largestMatch( this );
    
    var matchingLength = otherString.length,
        possibleMatch, index;
  
    while( matchingLength ){
      index = 0;
      while( index + matchingLength <= otherString.length ){
        possibleMatch = otherString.substr( index, matchingLength );
        if( ~this.indexOf( possibleMatch ) )
          return otherString.substr( index, matchingLength );
        index++;
      }  
      matchingLength--;
    }
    return '';
  };
  
  String.prototype.diff = function( newValue ){
    
    var largestMatch = this.largestMatch( newValue ),
        preNew, postNew, preOld, postOld;
    
    if(!largestMatch){
      return '<span class="deleted">' + this + <span><span class="inserted">' + newValue + </span>';
    } else {
      preNew = newValue.substr(0, newValue.indexOf( largestMatch ) ); 
      preOld = this.substr(0, this.indexOf( largestMatch ) ); 
      postNew = newValue.substr( preNew.length + largestMatch.length );
      postOld = this.substr( preOld.length + largestMatch.length );
      return preOld.diff( preNew ) + largestMatch + postOld.diff( postNew );
    }
  };

console.log(oldtext.diff(newtext))


.deleted{
   background-color : LightPink;
   text-decoration  : line-through
}
.inserted{
   background-color : PaleGreen
}
```

Is this possible to modify or is this outside the realm of possibility?

Thanks

Comment: Please specify what are the 'weird results'. What is the problem you're having? Why do you think it happens?

Comment: Sorry I should haven't used that term. This code wasn't what we needed, it was just the best I could do.

Comment: What if `newtext` has 4 lines instead of 3, what's the expected behavior? Although it's a legit question to ask, but it's a bit too large a question to be properly answered. Diff algorithm is hard. How about use some [prior art](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff) instead of rolling your own?

Answer (score 0):

Using this package for this task.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff

Thank you hackape!